# iOS: detect user moving phone left/right (not rotating, but moving)

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, accelerometer, core-motion

The goal is to detect how much the user moves the phone sideways. Imagine in the simplest scenario, the phone is flat on a table with the home button facing the ceiling.

If the user slides the phone left/right along the table, how can you detect the amount it was moved?

The code below doesn't seem to register the right values:

```
let motionManager = CMMotionManager()

override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    processUserMotion(forUpdate: currentTime)
}    

func processUserMotion(forUpdate currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        // 2
    if let data = motionManager.accelerometerData {
        // 3
        if fabs(data.acceleration.x) > 0.2 {
            // 4 How do you move the ship?
            print("X Acceleration: \(data.acceleration.x)")
        }

        if fabs(data.acceleration.y) > 0.2 {
            // 4 How do you move the ship?
            print("Y Acceleration: \(data.acceleration.y)")
        }

        if fabs(data.acceleration.z) > 0.2 {
            // 4 How do you move the ship?
            print("Z Acceleration: \(data.acceleration.y)")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Accelerometers only measure accelerations. At best you might see some acceleration when the phone starts moving left/right, and the deceleration when they stop moving left/right.

In theory, you could integrate the accelerations a couple of times to try to calculate a position (in basic physics/calculus, you can integrate acceleration to get velocity, and integrate velocity to get position).

In practice, accelerometer data is just too inaccurate and noisy for this to work with a reasonable degree of precision because with each integration step the errors get magnified.

I suggest you change your design so you're not reliant on absolute positions. Alternatively you could look into ARKit which uses cameras and image processing to establish the phone position in world space (although it wouldn't work in your example of the phone lying on a table because the camera would see nothing).

In case you're wondering, the reason that rotations are much simpler to work with is that accelerometers measure gravity as an acceleration, so it's always simple to work out which way is down. Then gyros (which measure rotation) are accurate enough to establish heading/azimuth pretty well, and can combine with a magnetic compass to correct the drift that comes from accumulated errors.

Replacing device rotation with device translation as a control method is one of those things that sounds simple, but is actually quite hard/impractical.

Comment: Thanks! Actually the table example was contrived, dumbed to simplify the problem. A real use case will be holding the phone in one hand with the thumb on the screen, sort of like the standard position for playing a game with one hand. Are you saying from this position, ARKit now lets you easily measure how much the user moves the device left/right whereas it wasn't really practical before ARKit?

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure ARKit can do this, and there wasn't really anything available prior to it. I haven't used ARKit myself so I can't speak for how easy it is to integrate into your code or how accurate it is, or whether there are other complications (e.g. perhaps it's laggy, or only works in good light levels, or gets confused if you use it on a busy street scene, etc, I just don't know)

Comment: Fair enough, hope you're right about ARKit being able to do this!

Comment: ARKit knows where you are in a 3D world, so yes it can be done.